# An element will disappear if any part of it out of page bounds

Tags: c#, winforms, reportviewer, rdlc

I wanted to render a reporting image with the winforms report viewer api and RDLC, but encountered the following problem. The problem can be reproduced with these steps:

1. Using `LocalReport` to render a specified RDLC file with
   `DeviceInfo`.
2. RDLC file is something like: a container with a large rectangle filled with some elements.
3. Resize the rectangle until its height or width out of range from size (`PageWidth` and `PageHeight` in `DeviceInfo`).
4. Run it and see the image rendered from RDLC.

Now, if part of rectangle is beyond the bounds of the page, the entire rectangle including its sub elements disappear, rather than just the parts which are out of bounds.

I'm not sure whether it is a bug or the result is as expected. But I am sure that it's better to cut off the out of range part rather than the entire element. Because I think it's common when we want to have a dynamic element such as a table with different data and whose element size will adjust depending on that data. If I am incorrect, please let me know.

Comment: Being that no one has answered, a possible but not ideal solution would be to use jquery to fish through the rendered report and hide the element you want dynamically. There'd be a lot of uncertainty with this method and the only reason I suggest it is encase you -need- a solution and still haven't found one.

Comment: Try checking your css, that sounds like a problem I've had outside of ReportViewer with the overflow property.